# WordPress redirects to installation page every after 2 days

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Hi I am having this issue for quite long time. My WordPress site shows installation page about every after 2 days. It fixes when I clear MySQL logfile (ib_logfiles0 and ib_logfile1). But it happens again. I made fresh WordPress installation, installed different security plugins in WordPress. Also, I installed fail2ban in my VPS to avoid Brute force attack and increased MySQL logfile size. But it shows again. Please help me.

By the way, I have multiple domain in the same VPS and all other domain works fine except this particular one.

Comment: Make sure that your VPS for this site is configured to use only one virtual machine. I would suspect some problem with load balancing between several machines where one of them is not updated and has old content.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your comment. But I installed only one Virtual Machine in my VPS. My VPS is hosted by EuroVPS and I don't think they will setup multiple Virtual Machine in my VPS.

Comment: ask them if they haven't accidentaly misconfigured something. I've had similar problem with Joomla site and it was related to some hard to spot configuration problem related to virtual machines.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I am going to ask them.